# Viewing console.log's of lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Does anyone know how to get to the `console.log's` when running an aws `lambda` function?

Its fine when I run the function in its test environment, but I want to see the logs when I run it in a production environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the output from the console in CloudWatch Logs.  Take a look at [Accessing Amazon CloudWatch Logs for AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html).